# Ckeditor character limitation with charcount plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, ckeditor

How can i **prevent** users to enter new characters **after max character** limit is reached ?

Ckeditor charcount plugin just shows me the remaining characters, i want it to stop at 0. But it goes minus integers.

Here's my html code.

```
<textarea id="myTextEditor1" name="myTextEditor"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('myTextEditor1', { 
            height: 200, 
            extraPlugins: 'charcount', 
            maxLength: 10, 
            toolbar: 'TinyBare', 
            toolbar_TinyBare: [
                 ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
                 ['Undo','Redo'],['Cut','Copy','Paste'],
                 ['NumberedList','BulletedList','Table'],['CharCount']
            ] 
        });
</script>
```

Do i have to use **onChange plugin** ? If i have to how can i limit users entering new characters ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used the ckeditor jQuery adapter for this.

```
<textarea id="myTextEditor1" name="myTextEditor"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var myEditor = $('#myTextEditor1');
        myEditor.ckeditor({ 
        height: 200, 
        extraPlugins: 'charcount', 
        maxLength: 10, 
        toolbar: 'TinyBare', 
        toolbar_TinyBare: [
             ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
             ['Undo','Redo'],['Cut','Copy','Paste'],
             ['NumberedList','BulletedList','Table'],['CharCount']
        ] 
        }).ckeditor().editor.on('key', function(obj) {
            if (obj.data.keyCode === 8 || obj.data.keyCode === 46) {
                return true;
            }
            if (myEditor.ckeditor().editor.document.getBody().getText().length >= 10) {
                alert('No more characters possible');
                return false;
            }else { return true; }

        });
    });
</script>
```

The keyCode check is to allow backspace and delete key presses. To use the jQuery adapter, don't forget to insert it:

```
<script src="/path-to/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is so helpful and it is working. I needed myEditor.ckeditor().editor.document.getBody().getText().length part so much. Thank you.