# how to integrate CKEditor textarea with character limit?

Tags: javascript, html

in simple html page CKeditor with character limit for only insert character(MAX=100 character).

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231626/ckeditor-character-limitation-with-charcount-plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ckeditor character limitation with charcount plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231626/ckeditor-character-limitation-with-charcount-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

For pure HTML one We have

```
<input type="text" id="Textbox" name="Textbox" maxlength="100" />
```

Kindly have a look over that ,if it not solve your problem, let me know.
Thank You

Comment: maxlength="100" attribute i try but not solve because ckeditor ignore all properties

Answer (score 0):

It has worked for me, use a data tag for example <input data-ml="400"...
then in the ckeditor config.js file I have used this property for wordcount

config.wordcount = {
showParagraphs: false,
showWordCount: true,
showCharCount: true,
countSpacesAsChars: false,
countHTML: false,
maxWordCount: -1,
**maxCharCount: this.element.data('ml') ? this.element.data('ml') : 400**
};